# background is not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

When I put the following css, Background image is not coming in ie8 and ie7.

```css
#bottom-thumb2{     
    width: 212px;
    height:300px;
    /*margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;*/
    padding:7px;
    width:23%;
    border-right:2px #cecece solid;
    background: url(../images/user912_modules_bg.png)repeat-y scroll right center rgb(255, 255, 255) ;
    font-size: 11px;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing space at this line `url(../images/user912_modules_bg.png)repeat-y` instead of `url(../images/user912_modules_bg.png) repeat-y`.

---

Try this:

```
background: url(../images/user912_modules_bg.png) repeat-y scroll right center rgb(255, 255, 255) ;
```

**or**

To avoid confusion, declare them separately. something like this:

```
background-image: url(../images/user912_modules_bg.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: right center;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) ;
```

Comment: incorrect for border syntax. it can be in either order you listed.

Comment: I know. Read examples on the link. Formal syntax can be in either order. Quoting: *Canonical order: order of appearance in the formal grammar of the values*

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Ya I understand your point now. sorry for being such a noob. I am removing that.

Answer (score 0):

What width should you be using?
What is the width of the image? 
212px or 23%? You are currently defining/using both...